# Open different activities according to the login credentials entered

Tags: android, sql-server

Below is my login activity.
It has a simple layout,where user enters his username and password and click login button.
A list of username and passwords is being stored in ms sql server.
And connection is also being established.
But the problem is on different combinations of usernames and passwords i want to open different activities.
How can i do it?

Lets say I have two combinations of username and password in my database-1.username1 , password1 (should open activity 1 on login button click)
2.username2, password2 (shoud open activity 2 on login button click)

Here is the code-----

```
public class Login extends Activity
{

    private static final String DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = "user@test.com:hello";

   // private UserLoginTask userLoginTask = null;
    private View loginFormView;
    private View progressView;
    ConnectionClass connectionClass;
    private AutoCompleteTextView emailTextView;
    private EditText passwordTextView;
    private Button btnlogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();

        emailTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        //loadAutoComplete();

        passwordTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnlogin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);

        class DoLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
        {
            String z = "";
            Boolean isSuccess = false;
            String userid = emailTextView.getText().toString();
            String password = passwordTextView.getText().toString();
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

        }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

            Toast.makeText(Login.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(isSuccess) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Activity1.class);//For any combination ,it will open activity1 now.
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            if(userid.trim().equals("")|| password.trim().equals(""))
                z = "Please enter User Id and Password";
            else
            {
                try {
                    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                    if (con == null) {
                        z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                    } else {
                        String query = "select EmailID,Password from Login_DB where EmailID='" + userid + "' and Password='" + password + "'";
                        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                        if(rs.next())
                        {
                            z = "Login successfull";
                            isSuccess=true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            z = "Invalid Credentials";
                            isSuccess = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    isSuccess = false;
                    z = "Exceptions";
                }
            }
            return z;
        }
        }
        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DoLogin doLogin = new DoLogin();// this is the Asynctask
                doLogin.execute("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need an attribute in your database that would let you know which activity to go to based on the username/password that was entered. There is no real way to manage this, at least efficiently, on the client side without having some sort of support from the backend. At least not that I can think of.

Comment: ya thats seems somewhat fine.Lets say i made a column in my databse table "GoTo ThisActivity" and give it values activity1 and activity2 in different rows.But then,Can you help me with the code?I am not getting what changes I have to make for this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table in your database that links usernames to activities, and then query it after authenticating the user.

Comment: ya thats seems somewhat fine.Lets say i made a column in my databse table "GoTo ThisActivity" and give it values activity1 and activity2 in different rows.But then,Can you help me with the code?I am not getting what changes I have to make for this in my code.

Comment: It would be more code than I have time to write for you, but if you try and post your effort, I will help you debug it.

Comment: Okay,Let me try then first

Comment: I ran a query to select the targetactivity name from the database and stored in a string variable, and then used the same string variable to generate an if else code in the onPostExecute method-->inside if(isSuccess)...But its not working,app is crashing now. @Tab Alleman

Comment: I would need to see that code to help debug it.   Can you either add it to your question above, or create a new one?   Also the error message you are getting when it crashes.

Comment: .I have edited the code,But still not achieved it.Code is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498474/how-to-open-different-activities-on-login-button-click