# How to open different activities on Login Button Click

Tags: android, sql-server

There is a Login activity and a Login database table it is connecting to.
Login db table(in sql server) has three columns "EmailID", "Password" and "Role".
Role can have any of these 4 values-"Normal","Admin","Superadmin","Client".
And for each role I need to open a different activity.

Below code is showing message "Exceptions" everytime,and not redirecting to any other activity then.

```
public class Login extends Activity {

 private static final String DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = "user@test.com:hello";
 private View loginFormView;
 private View progressView;
 ConnectionClass connectionClass;
 private AutoCompleteTextView emailTextView;
 private EditText passwordTextView;
 private Button btnlogin;
 private String activityy;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
  connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();

  emailTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
  passwordTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
  btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);



  //........................................................................................................

  class DoLogin extends AsyncTask < String, String, String > {
   String z = "";
   String role = "";
   Boolean isSuccess = false;
   String userid = emailTextView.getText().toString();
   String password = passwordTextView.getText().toString();
   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {}
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

    Toast.makeText(Login.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (isSuccess) {
     Intent i;
     if (role.equals("Admin")) {
      i = new Intent(Login.this, create_form.class);
      startActivity(i);
      finish();
     }
     else if (role.equals("Superadmin")) {
      i = new Intent(Login.this, report.class);
      startActivity(i);
      finish();
     }
     else if (role.equals("Client")) {
      i = new Intent(Login.this, Feedback_Form.class);
      startActivity(i);
      finish();
     }
     else if (role.equals("Normal")) {
      i = new Intent(Login.this, create_form.class);
      startActivity(i);
      finish();
     }


    }
   }
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String...params) {
    if (userid.trim().equals("") || password.trim().equals(""))
     z = "Please enter User Id and Password";
    else {
     try {
      Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
      if (con == null) {
       z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
      } else {
       String query = "select EmailID,Password from Login_DB where EmailID='" + userid + "' and Password='" + password + "'";

       Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


       String query2 = "select Role from Login_DB where EmailID='" + userid + "' and Password='" + password + "'";
       Statement stmt2 = con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(query2);

       if (rs.next()) {
        role = rs2.getString("Role");
        z = "Login Successful"
        isSuccess = true;
       } else {
        z = "Invalid Credentials";
        isSuccess = false;

       }


      }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
      isSuccess = false;
      z = "Exceptions";
     }
    }
    return z;
   }
  }
  btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

    DoLogin doLogin = new DoLogin(); // this is the Asynctask
    doLogin.execute("");
   }
  });
 }
}
```

LOGCAT IS BELOW----

```
04-08 07:40:40.611    6751-6751/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-08 07:40:40.643    6751-6756/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-08 07:40:40.723    6751-6751/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 53K, 7% free 2876K/3076K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
04-08 07:40:40.747    6751-6751/? I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 10.858MB for 8294412-byte allocation
04-08 07:40:40.751    6751-6759/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 10976K/11180K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
04-08 07:40:40.767    6751-6754/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 10976K/11180K, paused 3ms+0ms, total 14ms
04-08 07:40:40.907    6751-6751/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
04-08 07:40:40.911    6751-6751/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb871f128, tid 6751
04-08 07:40:41.011    6751-6751/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
04-08 07:40:41.011    6751-6751/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
04-08 07:40:41.271    6751-6751/? W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-08 07:40:41.271    6751-6751/? E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-08 07:40:41.395    6751-6751/? E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
04-08 07:40:41.411    6751-6751/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
04-08 07:40:41.415    6751-6751/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
04-08 07:40:41.415    6751-6751/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-08 07:40:42.719    6751-6751/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application V/RenderScript﹕ 0xb8764750 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
04-08 07:40:45.599    6751-6751/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-08 07:40:58.987    6751-6892/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1095K, 9% free 12596K/13836K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
```

Comment: @Ben Just Added above

Comment: Why don't you add some logs here to know if you are getting back the role:    if (rs.next()) {
        role = rs2.getString("Role");
        z = "Login Successful"
        isSuccess = true;
       } else {
        z = "Invalid Credentials";
        isSuccess = false;

       }

Comment: use else before if for every condition of creating intent except the first, or use switch case in place of if condition.

Comment: Yeah that was one of the mistakess.Thanks.I have edited the code above.But still it has not solved my problem,It is showing "Exceptions" message@HAXM

Comment: Did you post your full logcat ... i did not see any exception msg... rather the it directs another king of issue like Late-enabling CheckJNI